# Determine NBA conference seedings

Tags: code-golf

Heading into the final day of regular season games for the 2023 NBA season, the fifth to ninth seeds in the Western Conference were still very undecided. Four games would determine the seeding:

- New Orleans (N) at Minnesota (M)
- Utah at LA Lakers (L)
- Golden State (G) at Portland
- LA Clippers (C) at Phoenix

Let the Boolean variables `M L G C` denote the event of the respective team winning. Then the seeding depends on these variables as follows (taken from [this Twitter post](https://twitter.com/NBAPR/status/1644868977674297344)):

```
M L G C | 5 6 7 8 9
0 0 0 0 | N G C L M
0 0 0 1 | C N G L M
0 0 1 0 | G N C L M
0 0 1 1 | C G N L M
0 1 0 0 | N C L G M
0 1 0 1 | C L N G M
0 1 1 0 | G N C L M
0 1 1 1 | C G L N M
1 0 0 0 | C G M L N
1 0 0 1 | C G M L N
1 0 1 0 | G C M L N
1 0 1 1 | C G M L N
1 1 0 0 | C L G M N
1 1 0 1 | C L G M N
1 1 1 0 | G C L M N
1 1 1 1 | C G L M N
```

### Task

Given the bits `M L G C`, output the corresponding permutation of `C G L M N`, with the fifth seed first. For example, the input `M L G C = 1 0 1 0` should give `G C M L N`. You may use any five distinct symbols for the teams and may format the permutation in any reasonable manner.

Instead of taking `M` you may take its inverse `N`, with results altered accordingly (so the input `N L G C = 1 0 1 0` gives the same result as `M L G C = 0 0 1 0`, i.e. `G N C L M`). You may also combine the Boolean inputs into a single four-bit integer, but in any case you must clearly indicate which bit or bit position corresponds to which game.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf); fewest bytes wins.

---

*The actual results had all bits set to 1, resulting in the seeding*

```
5 6 7 8 9
C G L M N
```

Comment: Would it be possible to give the algorithm that the conference uses to decide seeding, or is that too complicated here? Are there instances where changing the result of a game affects the relative ordering of teams not playing in that game?

Comment: @xnor It seems that if the LA Lakers win then their relative ordering depends on whether or not the LA Clippers win.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org)<sup>(1)</sup>, 68 bytes

Expects a single 4-bit integer, where the least significant bit is `C`. Returns an array of letters.

```javascript
n=>[...'MGNCL'].sort(_=>~(q/=2)%2,q=Buffer(')!-%*$-ESS[SCC+#')[n]*4)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc2xDoIwEIDhnac4o@R6AhWJcdE6SIyLunQkxBCkRmOuWqqL0VdHRqd/@ZL/Wr2qtnaXu0/YnprOqI7VqpBS4n57yHdYytY6L45q9RWPicoozOKHWj@NaZxAGiTheJRstC50nkdDpILL8Yw6Y51gUJAugGEJ03nfKCJ4BwC15dbeGnmzZ8HSW@3dhc@C5L06aV/1t4wgAgSBff5E9kdmMWCKvUPCGIxgokXw6X4)

#### How?

We use `sort()` on the array `['M','G','N','C','L']` with a callback function which ignores its arguments. Given the input \$n\in[0\dots15]\$, the result of the sort solely depends on a seed \$q_n=4k_n\$ where \$k_n\in[33\dots91]\$ is the code of a printable ASCII character picked from a lookup string.

At each iteration, the expression `~(q /= 2) % 2` in the callback function returns either \$0\$ or \$-1\$.

*<sub>(1) This code relies on the fact that `sort()` is stable (which is now a requirement of the ECMAScript specification) and that the array entries are processed in a specific order. This may fail on older engines.</sub>*

Comment: `sort` is stable for arrays with less than 10 elements (or maybe 12, i don't know) on old version of Node (which doesn't implement new stable TimSort).

Comment: @tsh Yes, 10 is also the boundary I had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 72 bytes

```python
lambda a:oct(ord('ʜٔќڌˢ܊ќڡڄڄӄڄܐܐӠڠ'[int(a,2)]))[2:]+a[0]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3PXISc5NSEhUSrfKTSzTyi1I01E_NuTnl4pxbPacX3ekC0gtvtdxquQzEdybcmXB5wa0F6tGZeSUaiTpGmrGamtFGVrHaidEGsRDzbjGylhQl5hXnJJakxpckJuWkKtgqFJcU6eUmZqeCZTSqlQyVrJT8lHS4FGBAyQgo4o4iYgwUcUYRMQGK-KCIGABFfJVqNbkKikAuUvL1cXdWqFEwNTO3sFTS5ErLL1LIVMjMUwBam56qYWimaQXWXAF0UlJmnkYm2PF6RVmlxSUaJjrqBuqaYPl8oHyaRgWUA1Kdrwf3lAaa9yCqIA6o0FFQqlHSAerRhITGggUQGgA)

Takes in a Python string of 0s or 1s corresponding to the wins/losses as described above; outputs a string of length 5 containing the digits 0 through 5, where the mapping is

```
{"1":"N",
 "2":"G",
 "3":"C",
 "4":"L",
 "0":"M"}
```

---

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 74 bytes

```python
lambda a:ord('卜綌〴稈孲薢〴窼祂祂㋲祂蔶蔶㑚窪'[int(a,2)])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3vXISc5NSEhUSrfKLUjTUn_bOeb6t53HDlucrOp6u3fRi2iIQe9We50ubgOhx9yYg-WLKNiB6PHHW81Wr1KMz80o0EnWMNGM1ISbeYuQqKUrMK85JLEmNL0lMyklVsFUoLinSy03MTgXLaFQrGSlZKfkp6XApwICSIVDEHUXEGCjijCJiAhTxQRExAIr4KtVqchUUgdyh5Ovj7qxQo2BqZm5hqaTJlZZfpJCpkJmnALQ2PVXD0EzTCqy5AuikpMw8jUzNaCOrWL2irNLiEg0THXUDdU2wfD5QPk2jAsqpgHhAI19TD-4zDTQ_QpRCXFGho6BUo6QD1AgNkgULIDQA)

A simpler earlier approach, using a different mapping.

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 50 bytes

```
Ｎθ≔⪪⪫⟦§59θC§38ＮG⎇Ｎ§47θ¹L0⎇ＮN2M¦M6N⟧ω²θＷ⁻θυ⊞υ⌈ι⭆υ⌈ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYxLC8IwEITv/RUhp12IUN9KT@JBFFMK9SYeYi020MY2TXz8@piCiAoelt2dmW@yQujsIkrn1qq2JrbVMdfQYBQs2laeFaR1KQ1sLlLBfmHW6pTfgY7nlJEGGaFLf7zl4cx/nz3YRVZe3OVaCf2AL/ODHE1fhf2O2Ib/ERoPuHcpn8QUD4zcvDbADo6CWyHLnACXyrbQMGIRSWLbAiwjXNxlZSuQ6IOJlspAavw6c1H/@Bg5Fwb9wI/rXcsn) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input in the order `C G L M`. Explanation: Each team is given a rating depending on whether it wins or loses, except if the LA Lakers win then their rating also depends on whether the LA Clippers win or not. It then remains to output the teams in descending order of rating.

```
Ｎθ
```

Input `C`.

```
≔⪪⪫⟦§59θC§38ＮG⎇Ｎ§47θ¹L0⎇ＮN2M¦M6N⟧ω²θ
```

Build up a string of teams and ratings. First is `C`, which has a rating of either `5` or `9`, then `G` has a rating of `3` or `8`, then `L` has a rating of `1`, `4` or `7`, then either `N` has a rating of `0` and `M` has a rating of `2` or `M` has a rating of `0` and `N` has a rating of `6`. The string is then split into pairs of characters ready for sorting.

```
Ｗ⁻θυ⊞υ⌈ι
```

Sort the teams in descending order of rating.

```
⭆υ⌈ι
```

Output just the teams without the ratings.

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 94 bytes

Modified from [@97.100.97.109's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/260164/110802).

---

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVBNSwMxEL3vrxgWYROoi59VF1vQIiJYPVhP4iGuaY1mk5KNUtGCeBLUgyAexJMgSMGLiCf/TZH6L@rEtCKGSXgzyby8N3nKJOuLrKmNhdwlcaql5KkVWsXZoWU7kgeB3tnHElSZUHASAOzyOmSYEGYaeQILxrDjrQ1rhGps0wQ2lbBQgpO@e1cnLPFXNFlRthR@Xj/03q@6Z2@954vPl9evu0eHOx@9p3OM7uUrnl@37xjdm/tepxMSbOMNbuImMznHhLACTFDaB1xHTII1TOWSWV5zchPU2dyq7DFTAHduoxSskGgigtEyRGtRAaJxj5cdnvS44vCUx6sOj3lcjWjgfmqiBysVCauryxU4henizOxc6O/q2gARMD8KY3CorJAwXqQ/oxpqbKGKoQ@rF4Vi5tiPhQgaG37E0Rs63K1pMvXz@W/1D4tGljpp0b8lx6yR07PFGVpNoVT@N5W4we26WZI5J2kBUkrj7MB3DLiG9vJwpIXuRnRr4K0duN0O@t8)

```scala
def f(a:String):Int="卜綌〴稈孲薢〴窼祂祂㋲祂蔶蔶㑚窪"(Integer.parseInt(a, 2))
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVBNSwMxEL3vrxgWYRNoFz/qV1FBi4jQ6kE9FQ9xTWs0m5RsLC1aEE@CehDEg3gSBCl4EfHkvylS/0WdNFUUkuHNTPLmvckSJtlgINKGNhYyl8WJlpInVmgVp8eW7UkeBHrvEEtQYULBSQCwz2uQYkKYqWdFWDaGtatb1ghV36VF2FHCwuLwJUCTSagVwXdhcQnWlWsyB8PP64f@@1Xv7K3/fPH58vp19@hw96P/dI6nd/mK8ev2HU/v5r7f7YYEf/M6N3GDmYxjQlgOJin9HWUNU5lklm876UXU3KiWDpjJgYu7OBkrJJqMIL8E0UaUg2jC4zWHpzwuOVzwuOzwuMeViAbDUQ10Y6UiYaW8VoJTmJ6ZnZsPvYyaNkAELORhHI6VFRImZuhoG15kC2X8GLF6RShm2n5BRNDY8CZHc2hxf1uTwnD6b/UPi0aWGmnRvyXHrJHTs8Upek3cpv@vJa5zu2lWZcZJkoOE0jg98j9GXD/2snCshe7GdGvkrRO42wkGg28)

```scala
import scala.collection.mutable

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val f: String => Int = a => "卜綌〴稈孲薢〴窼祂祂㋲祂蔶蔶㑚窪"(Integer.parseInt(a, 2))
    val translateTable: Map[Char, Char] = Map('2' -> 'N', '1' -> 'G', '3' -> 'C', '4' -> 'L', '0' -> 'M')

    println("MLGC | 56789")
    for (i <- 0 until 16) {
      val x = Integer.toBinaryString(i).reverse.padTo(4, '0').reverse
      val o = f(x)
      val ox = o.toString.map(c => translateTable.getOrElse(c, c)).mkString
      println(s"$x | $ox")
    }
  }
}
```